# Cakephp Model Saving Data Twice

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am using the version Cakephp 2.9.3 and when I am saving the data by using save method of the model, the data is being saved twice in my database table but I have checked that the save call is triggered only once.

Here is the code for my Controller:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('Log', 'Model');

class DashboardController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $data = array(
            'type' => 'subscribers_log',
            'message' => 'sample text',
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            'hostname' => 'finakle.com',
            'uri' => '/'
        );

        $log = new Log;
        $log->save($data);
    }

}
```

Here is the sample screenshot of my database table:

[Database Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzx45.png)

Comment: $this->Log->create(); $this->Log->save($data);

Comment: Thanks @yBrodsky for the comment but I already tried that and I am still getting 2 entries in the table.

Comment: don't you have something in your model in some callback?

Comment: And how exactly have you checked that the code only runs once? Such information should be in your question! Given that there are no precautions in your controller action, chances are good that it is being run twice.

Comment: Hi @ndm, For testing purposes I have overrided the save method in my Log model and just echoed some random string in the method and when I hit the browser I observed that the string is printed only once on the screen.

Comment: Hi @yBrodsky, There are no callback functions in my Model.

Comment: That's not a very good method for testing this, as it would always only render one message, no matter how many times the browser reloads the page.

Comment: use should write to the the log file instead of echoing it.

Comment: Hello Guys, Thank you for the help. I have found that the video tag in my layout file was causing the action to load twice. I included the video file using $this->Html->media() and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had built a custom layout for the application and further analyzed that in my layout file I was playing a video file using normal HTML tags. This somehow was causing the issue. Below mentioned is the code:

```
<div class="hero-video">
    <video autoplay muted="muted" loop="loop" poster="#" id="hero_video">
        <source src="resources/images/New/In-And-Out.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="resources/images/New/In-And-Out.webm" type="video/webm" />
    </video>
</div>
```

But then I changed the code to include the video file through cakephp media tag as shown below:

```
<div class="hero-video">
    <?php echo $this->Html->media(
        array(
            'In-And-Out.mp4',
            array(
                'src' => 'In-And-Out.webm',
                'type' => "video/webm"
            )
        ),
        array(
            'autoplay' => 'true',
            'muted' => 'muted',
            'loop' => 'loop',
            'poster' => '#',
            'id' => 'hero_video'
        )
    ); ?>
</div>
```

This resolved my issue.